# Angular UI modal within another angular UI Modal

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have created  an angular UI Modal within another angular UI bootstrap Modal Ok button function. I have a input form when you click on submit button if the form is dirty then it should open error messages dialog(using angular UI bootstrap modal) and close input form dialog box. I am able to this using  modal dismiss function. Once you click on Error message cancel button it should close error dialog box and should open input form dialog with already entered data(assuming user entered only few inputs and other skipped and clicked on OK). How do I get an handle to input form modal from error modal controller? Thanks in advance for your suggestions

Comment: Demo code using http://plnkr.co/ or similar would get you an answer in no time, otherwise it is hard to get what you are after.

Comment: Thanks for reply. here is plunker: Please see script.js file http://plnkr.co/edit/U9eaOzCCj0GLXQQhYpwW?p=catalogue

Comment: the idea is to have a _life_, working (or at least breaking) plunker, not dumping JavaScript only. Like this is missing essential info: markup, library version, AngularJS version etc.

Comment: Sorry about that.I was looking for some suggestions about how to get a handle to parent modal from child modal(as shown in script). Otherwise,I would have posted working example only.I thought people like you would answer just by seeing code sample since I was not asking for code fix.Anyway, I will try to post some working example.

Comment: I don't know how to add CDN for angular UI bootstrap.So, example is not working. But,I have created templates and JS info. So, I hope you will make it work and suggestion/answer for me. Sorry to bother you. Thanks for your all help.

Comment: Anybody is there to help me. I know angular is not providing this functionality out of the box. At least, some directions to try myself... Don't know how to open the same modal once it is closed.